# What is the callback for network state changes in Metro apps?

Tags: callback, windows-8

I want to get the callback triggered by a network state change on Metro apps. Is such a callback available? If not, what would be a good alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NetworkStatusChanged event:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged += NetworkInformation_NetworkStatusChanged;
}

void NetworkInformation_NetworkStatusChanged(object sender)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Network Status Changed");
}
```

Comment: Thanks John ! This is what I wanted !

Comment: @JohnyDgoode If this answers your question, you can click the checkmark under the voting area to mark it as the answer so others know that this question is answered.